# Can't connect to the SQL Server while using Microsoft authentication in Windows 10

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using Windows 10 on my laptop. I have an Azure account and I use to login to my computer. I have installed SQL Server and Management Studio under this Azure account. So I can login to SQL Server with Management Studio anytime and I don't have any problem with that.

[image]

Now I have created another account on my computer with Microsoft Email ID. I can login with this hotmail email Id to the computer. But this time I can't login to SQL Server with Management Studio.

I get this error:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how I can login to SQL Server while using the Microsoft account?

Comment: Either, you need to create a login and corresponding users in all relevant databases for your Microsoft account, or you need to log in to SQL Server using not your MS account, but a dedicated SQL Server login (name + password)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a default login for SQL Server with a UN = "sa" and its password usually is set while installation. try to figure out that and you may be able to connect.